# multiple threads access array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, initialization, final

```
class EverythingMustBeInAClass
{
    private final int i = 42;
    private final int[] a = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19};
}
```

The fact that `i` is declared `final` guarantees that all threads see the same int value 42 (instead of 0).

The fact that `a` is declared `final` guarantees that all threads see the same array *reference*.

But how do I make sure that all threads see the same array *elements* (instead of 0s)? Do I have to synchronize access to the array, even if I never intend to change the array elements later on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`final` guarantees not only that the array reference is seen but also that the object itself has been fully constructed and initialized.  So the values in the array will also be seen by all threads.

Here's a good link on the subject: [Thread-safety with the Java final keyword](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml)

To quote:

> The fields on any object accessed via a final reference are also guaranteed to be at least as up to date as when the constructor exits.

However, it is important to note that the `a` array is *not* immutable so, for example, you could set `a[0] = 10` and that update would not be synchronized.  But as long as you *don't* change any values in `a` you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are never going to change the contents you are safe due to "happens before semantics" and final.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not have to synchronize accesses if the data structure uses the keyword final.  You can have as many simultaneous reads as you need as long as you never write to the variable.  If you do not use the final keyword, you need to lock the variable anytime you want to access it.